# Does the optimizer filter subqueries with outer where clauses

Tags: sql, performance

Take the following query:

```
select * from
(
  select a, b
  from c
    UNION
  select a, b
  from d
)
where a = 'mung'
order by b
```

Will the optimizer generally work out that I am filtering a on the value 'mung' and consequently filter mung on each of the queries in the subquery.

OR

will it run each query within the subquery union and return the results to the outer query for filtering (as the query would perhaps suggest)

In which case the following query would perform better :

```
select * from
(
  select a, b
  from c
  where a = 'mung'
    UNION
  select a, b
  from d
  where a = 'mung'
)
order by b
```

Obviously query 1 is best for maintenance, but is it sacrificing much performace for this?

Which is best?

**Edit**
Sorry I neglected to add the **order by** clause in the queries to indicate why it all needed to be a subquery in the first place!

**Edit**
Ok, I thought it was going to be a simple answer, but I forgot I was talking about databases here! Running it through the analyser indicates that there is no optimization going on, but this could of course be because I only have 4 rows in my tables. I was hoping for a simpler yes or no.. Will have to set up some more complex tests.

I am on mySQL at the moment, but I am after a general answer here...

Comment: Might be my own ignorance but why not ask the optimizer what it will do by asking it for its suggested execution plan (show execution plan) and look at how it attacks the problem? Its obviously not a complete picture but it would give you an idea what hints its using and where.

Comment: IT DEPENDS.  Sometimes it will, and sometimes it will not.  It more often *will* if you change that UNION to a UNION ALL though.

Comment: And it certainly depends very *extremely* on what brand, edition and version of SQL you are using.

Comment: I'd assume the algebrizer would work this out for itself but would be interested in the documented behaviour for derived tables as well.

Comment: The only documented behavior of a product optimizer for something like this would normally be something to the effect of "the ISO standard allows our optimizer to do this if it thinks that it should".  whether it can actually figure that out though is a product quality/feature issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT x.a, 
       x.b
  FROM TABLE_X x
 WHERE x.a = 'mung'
UNION
SELECT y.a, 
       y.b
  FROM TABLE_Y y
 WHERE y.a = 'mung'
```

- The subquery is unnecessary in the given context
- The query above will use indexes if available on column "a"; Using the subquery method, there's no index to utilize
- Use `UNION ALL` if you don't have to be concerned with duplicates - it will be faster than `UNION`

Comment: Apologies, I should have put the order by in the queries to indicate why a subquery is necessary in the first place. My silliness.. Still your other two points indicate that the optimizer will not be able to work out that the filter should be applied to the subqueries?

Comment: @Mongus Pong: Viewing the explain plan would be best to determine what the optimizer is doing, and it's possible it will be different between database vendors (if not versions too)